# Zend Forms email element changing to text

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm trying to create an input of type `email` in Zend Forms but I cannot accomplish the desired result.

I've created a custom class:

```php
namespace AAA\Forms\Elements;

class Email extends \Zend_Form_Element_Text
{
    function __construct($name, $label, $required)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->setAttrib('type', 'email');
        $this->setLabel($label)->setRequired($required);
    }
}
```

And then I'm using it like this:

```php
class Application_Form_Register extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        // …
        $email = new AAA\Forms\Elements\Email('email', 'E-mail:', true);
        $this->addElement($email);
        // …
    }
}
```

And what I get is:

```html
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" type="email">
```

Note the two `type` parameters.

I have set HTML5 doctype (`$documentType = new Zend_View_Helper_Doctype(); $documentType->doctype('HTML5');` in *Bootstrap.php*) and I have also tried this:

```php
function __construct($name, $label, $required)
{
    $options = array();
    $options['type'] = 'email';
    parent::__construct($name, $options);
    // …
}
```

I've read [Zend HTML5 Form element types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433555/zend-html5-form-element-types) but none of the answers work. I've tried also Glitch library but the result is the same.

Anyone knows how to force Zend Framework to use HTML5 form controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to implement your own view helper for rendering the email form element as well.

`Zend_Form_Element_Text` uses the `formText` view helper (`Zend/View/Helper/FormText.php`) to render the HTML input and it is hard coded to output `<input type="text"` when rendering the element.

Two possible ways to handle this would be to:

- Remove the `ViewHelper` decorator from the element and use the `ViewScript` helper to render the element.
- Make your own view helper `formEmail` almost identical to `formText` except that it outputs `type="email"`; and set the public `$helper` property in your Element class to `formEmail`.  You will have to register the path to the `formEmail` helper using `Zend_View::addHelperPath()` so it will be found by the `ViewHelper` decorator.

Comment: I used the second option. For any future reference ‒ I added `resources.view.helperPath.AAA = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/AAA/Forms/ViewHelpers"` to application.ini, created `AAA_FormEmail` class in that directory identical to `Zend_View_Helper_FormText` from ZF with only `text` changed to `email` and set the helper property of my Email element class: `$this->helper = 'formEmail';`. Thank you!